# Jquery: stylize elements, which loads after some actions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form-configurator. When I choose some element from a dropdown, the page loads other elements of the form via AJAX. jQuery can't stylize those new elements. For example:

```
$('select').selectmenu({style: 'dropdown'});
```

It would be nice to use the "ready" or "load" events for these elements:

```
$('select').live('ready', function(){
    $(this).selectmenu({style: 'dropdown'});
})
```

Are there any alternatives?

Comment: Can't you just put something in your CSS targeting `<select>` tags?

Comment: Or apply style in the ajax callback

Comment: You can also use the "success" or "complete" callback of your ajax to apply the styling when things are loaded.

Comment: It is forbidden to change anything. I can only work with stuff that  is given on page